# Nextcloud integration with wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7, plugin-ninja-forms

We have a contact form on our website and we want to allow user to upload pdf file.

We would like to uploaded file to be in turn uploaded to our nextcloud system.

Could anyone please tell me if such a plugin exist or any other way to achieve this?

We found https://wpfilebase.com but the developper is nowere to be found so buying it is not really an option.

Thank all